# Korn shell - print empty array

Tags: arrays, printf, ksh

I have the problem that an empty array is printed as two brackets when using ksh. The output from

```
#!/bin/ksh

a=()
printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}"
```

is

```
(
)
```

When using bash, an empty line is printed. How do I get this behavior in ksh?

When I try to check if the array is empty, it has always one element:
e.g.

```
echo ${#a[@]}
```

gives me 1 as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`man ksh` says `varname=(assign_list)` for 'Indexed array assignment'. `assign_list` is not optional.

So, it is undefined what happens if you do `a=()`. It seems, that a normal variable is created.

```
b= 
echo "${#b[@]}"
```

gives a 1 too. You are forcing the normal variable to act like an array.

If you `unset a[0]`, or `unset a` then `echo ${#a[@]}` will give you `0`and printing the then undefined array/variable will print an empty string.

If you want to define the variable as being an array, you should use `typeset -a a`, then you get an array with no elements, printing as expected (an existing normal variable will be unset). And your code is clearly showing how the variable/array should be treated.